# Bulk BIND zones creation

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, ubuntu-12.04, shell-scripting, bulk-action

How can I create zones for 50 domains on Ubuntu 12 VPS? I have webmin (which allows me to use BIND to create/ manage zones). I was able to figure out what gets created to add a zone successfully.

But creating record for 50 domains is time consuming and I will make errors.

What is the best way to add the same quickly? Can someone share an example of shell script or something to achieve it? Or some third party tools which can help me achieve the same?

The format for each zones will be the same as below:

```
File 1: /etc/bind/named.conf.local

zone "dummy.org" {
    type master;
    file "/var/lib/bind/dummy.org.hosts";
    };

----------------------
File 2: /var/lib/bind/<dummy.org.hosts>


$ttl 38400
dummy.org.       IN      SOA     abc.com. dns.abc.com (
                        1366568118
                        10800
                        3600
                        604800
                        38400 )
dummy.org.       IN      NS      ns1.abc.com.
dummy.org.       600     IN      A       <MyIP>    
www.dummy.org.   600     IN      A       <My IP>
```

Comment: If you can't script this you really should consider learning some bash scripting.

Comment: Well, I am still learning stuff. If you can point to few bash scripting tutorials, I will be more than glad to learn

Answer (score 1):

For starters, you should to adjust your zone writing methodology to be reusable between zones. Avoid using RRs ending in a dot *unless you explicitly have to*.

1. You're not taking advantage of the `@` character, which represents the current origin. By default, the origin scope for a zone file will be the same as the "zone" declaration in named.conf. (put more simply, the `@` character will always default to being what you specified after "zone" in named.conf, with a period appended to the end if it's not already present)
2. You're not taking advantage of the fact that lines beginning with a tab or whitespace (you must omit the name of the record) are considered to have the same name scope as the preceding record.
3. If you need to define a massive number of zones that do not have any uniquely distinguishing records and the only thing that changes is the name of the zone, they can all share the same zone file. You just need to make sure that any references to the zone itself adhere to tip #1. (use `@`)
4. You only need to include a trailing dot when referring to data outside of the current zone. `www` will refer to `www.dummy.org.` inside of this zone. `ns1.abc.com.` requires the dot at the end because it's outside of the `dummy.org.` zone and should be left alone.

Putting the above to use within your current example:

- the `SOA` record could list `@` instead of `dummy.org.` (tip #1)
- the `NS` record and first `A` record can either omit the record name entirely (tip #2), or replace `dummy.org.` with `@` (tip #1)
- `www.dummy.org.` can just be `www` (tip #4)

Remove the uniquely identifying data as described above. At that point, this zone file becomes a starting point for any other zones that share the same data. Copy the zone file to other zone files as many times as would be appropriate, *then* concern yourself with the data that is unique to each of your zones.

Comment: :Thank you for writing a detailed answer. I am not an expert in BIND/ DNS. I have some basic information of how DNS works. all my domains need to point to the same server with same details. So, that being said, what changes will I need to do to enable least changes and still allow multiple zones to be created with ease?

Comment: I do exactly this for about two dozen domains, the vast majority simply use a symlink to the generic domain, and a few get copied so an extra A record or whatever can be added, makes maintenence so much easier. I also have a trivial makefile that takes my zone files (all named by domain) and creates the relevent chunk of named.conf, it also can do the same for slaving zones.